# Is there a way to programatically execute the "Create NSMangedObjectSubclass" command in XCode 4?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, xcode4

I find it incredibly tedious every time I edit a core data model in the XCode model builder to select "Editor -> Create NSManagedObjectSubclass", then select the project group and directory in which to place the generated files, and agree that yes, I do want to replace their old versions.

It would be really great to have a one line shell command to generate these with a default group and directory. Does such a tool exist? If not, how would one go about writing such a tool?

Comment: You may want to investigate [mogenerator](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator). It doesn't do the exact same thing that Xcode does, but it is basically a tool to regenerate CoreData classes as part of your build system, without interfering with custom code you may want to write for the class.

Comment: @KevinBallard, you should make that an answer

Comment: @TomHarrington: If you insist :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to automate Xcode like that. The closest you can come is the generic UI automation functionality in AppleScript, but what you're asking for is pretty complex.

Instead, you may want to investigate [mogenerator](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator). It doesn't do the exact same thing that Xcode does, but it is basically a tool to regenerate CoreData classes as part of your build system, without interfering with custom code you may want to write for the class.

Comment: That looks perfect for what I'm trying to do. Thanks!